# What is the option in C# having the same capability like 'IN' in SQL?

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to search more than one condition in an `if` conditional block - the same like the IN operator does in SQL.

```
public class Check{

    int [] arr = {1, 2, 5, 9, 7, 11, 89};
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    {
      if(arr[i]==1||arr[i]==5||arr[i]==7||arr[i]==89)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("The number was found.");
      }
    }
```

> Is there a solution for this kind of result?

```
if (arr[i] in(1, 5, 7, 89)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The No Is Found.");
}
```

Comment: Many built-in container classes already have a built-in method named `Contains()` that does this. And if you create your own custom container class, you should include a similar method in it as well.

Comment: Does this search for conditional statements?

Comment: If you have a C# container class object that contains multiple conditions, then it would search for a condition, yes.  if, for example, you create an instance of `List<condition> x = new List<condition> {cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4, cond5};` then `x.Contains(cond1)` would return true, and `x.Contains(cond12)` would return false;

Comment: Gointg To Try This One ..Thanks For Help. http://stackoverflow.com/users/32632/charles-bretana

Comment: you have to create a class to hold a "condition" - however you need that to be defined / structured.  If it's just "any C# expression that evaluates as true or false", then you need to look into C# lambda expressions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: yes working but Still If statement looking better.

Comment: It would really help if you could provide a [mcve] rather than just showing pseudo-code. It's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Well that's not *quite* a [mcve] given that you appear to have put a statement directly in a class declaration, but at least it makes it more answerable...

Comment: As You asked for it. I edited the code using a **Console Application Code** @JonSkeet

Comment: @RajanMishra: No, just deleting your previous identical comment and adding it again doesn't fix the problem I highlighted...

Comment: @JonSkeet i wasn't doing that...but thanks for the help Sir.

Comment: What weren't you doing? You definitely had basically the same comment before my comment at 14:21:37Z, and then you deleted it and added one at 14:23:32Z... and the question *still* has code which wouldn't compile due to having statements directly in a class declaration.

Comment: Yeah that was a try to highlight your name ..and i found it soon that its not working. don't mind it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing in C# as a *language* that's equivalent to `IN`, no... but you can achieve a similar effect easily.

The simplest approach is to probably to use `System.Linq` and `Contains` against an array:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Check{

    static void Main()
    {
        int[] candidates = {1, 2, 5, 9, 7, 11, 89};
        // This is the members of the "in" clause - the
        // the values you're trying to check against
        int[] targets = { 1, 5, 7, 89 };
        foreach (int candidate in candidates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                targets.Contains(candidate) ?
                $"{candidate} is in targets" :
                $"{candidate} is not in targets");
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a `HashSet<int>` - that would be more efficient if you had a large number of targets:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Check{

    static void Main()
    {
        int[] candidates = {1, 2, 5, 9, 7, 11, 89};
        var targets = new HashSet<int> { 1, 5, 7, 89 };
        foreach (int candidate in candidates)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                targets.Contains(candidate) ?
                $"{candidate} is in targets" :
                $"{candidate} is not in targets");
        }
    }
}
```